# Avoiding string when Calling laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel

This is relationship in model

```
public function article_children() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id',self::PRIMARY_KEY);
}
```

I am calling it with this line

```
$article_type = ArticleType::with('article_children')->find($id);
```

My code works nice but what annoys me is that I have to pass method name 'article_children' as string and I am trying to avoid that ...

ideal solution would be

```
$article_type = ArticleType::with(ArticleType::someReferenceToMethodArticleChildren)->find($id);
```

So In far far away future I will have option to just CRTL + CLick on that reference and it would lead me directly to relation method in PHP-Storm.

If any one knows the answer how to improve that part of code let me know :)

Comment: Laravel Facades are not static classes, so you can't create a static reference to the underlying class properties in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working. On your `ArticleType` model, add:

```
public static $relChildren = "article_children";
```

Then when using `::with()`, you can use:

```
ArticleType::with(ArticleType::$relChildren)->first();
```

I don't know if that would solve your issue of trying to find the reference via PHPStorm, but this seemed to work for string substituting.